# Can ServletContext be used inside a jsp?

Tags: jsp, servlets

ServletContext scope is the application level scoe in Servlets. However in JSP, application level scope is provided by the implicit object application. Can we still use ServletContext inside a jsp. How is it different from application implicit object and why should we use it at all in a JSP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The application is the ServletContext. It is the same object, in JSP it might be easier to use it instead of getServletContext method.

See code like this:

```
<%
out.println("app: " + application);
out.println("context: " + getServletContext());
%>
```

prints:

```
app: com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.facade.ServletContextFacade@774cfa76 
context: com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.facade.ServletContextFacade@774cfa76
```

Answer (score 0):

The implicit objects are consider as pre-defined variables that we can use without explicit declaration, the application object is the same ServletContext object that you get when you call the getServletContext() in your servlet.

Every JSP is translate and compiled as a servlet but the JSP specification gives us a level of abstracion about the implementation and I think that is the reason for these implicit objects so you don't need to know about the servlet espeficiation.
Also you can use the EL (Expression Language) and it also defines other implicit objects, so in your case you can use the application context in this way:

**JSP**

```
<%= application.getAttribute("myVariable") %>
```

**EL**

```
${applicationScope.myVaraible}
```

An important difference of the `applicationScope` EL object is only a Map to access to the attributes, it is not a ServletContext object.